# Getting error An SQL error "-204" occurred while processing the SELECT string in the Action String parameter when executing DB2 EXPORT IXF?

Tags: sql, db2, export

I am executing below command on Shell bash after connecting to the database
the textfile below has table names in the DB2 database like

```
TABLE1
TABLE2
..
TABLEN
```

---

```
for tablenam in $(cat textfile)
do
 db2 'EXPORT TO $PPL_IXFDRV/PREBKP/tablenam.IXF OF~
  IXF MESSAGES /dev/null~
  SELECT * FROM $SCHEMA.tablenam'
done
```

When I run this I get below error

> SQL3022N  An SQL error "-204" occurred while processing the SELECT string in
>   the Action String parameter.

I have tried the above command with single quote like below

```
for tablenam in $(cat textfile)
do
 db2 EXPORT TO $PPL_IXFDRV/PREBKP/tablenam.IXF OF~
  IXF MESSAGES /dev/null~
  SELECT \* FROM $SCHEMA.tablenam
done
```

This also gives me the same result

What I am trying to do here is unload in IXF format DB2 tables present in the list "textfile" in the Database substituting tablenam in the repeated commands for db2 EXPORT

Comment: Clearly Db2 cannot find the table you're trying to export. Use the `-v` switch with `db2` to echo the actual command being executed; you'll probably see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for tablenam in $(cat textfile)
do
 db2 "EXPORT TO ${PPL_IXFDRV}/PREBKP/${tablenam}.IXF OF
  IXF 
  SELECT * FROM ${SCHEMA}.${tablenam}"
done
```

Comment: I tried this just now it is giving same result, I did put echo $tablenam just above db2 EXPORT command and it did display all the table names line by line, so unsure if the issue is that tablenam is not getting replaced by the table names inside textfile perhaps, I am not sure need some help

Comment: Must be `${tablenam}` instead of `tablenam` inside the loop. Check the updated answer.